# Debug.Print in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, debug-print

In VBA `Debug.Print` prints to the Immediate window.

I just found out that using a semicolon (`;`) makes it print at the position of the [caret/text cursor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation) which seems odd.

```
Debug.Print "a" & "b" & "c"
Debug.Print ; "a"; "b"; "c"
Debug.Print "a", "b", "c"
```

Prints the following.

```
abc
abc
a             b             c
```

That was my main question before I found it in the documentation and understood it a little more.

> [Use a semicolon (;) to position the insertion point immediately following the last character displayed.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/print-method#syntax)

My question now is if it is possible to use a [named argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments) like this:

```
Debug.Print object:="..."
```

Intellisense usually helps finding the arguments' names but it doesn't list any.

I also tried `object` or `outputlist` like it shows in the docs but it throws an error.

Is `Debug.Print` different in that regard?

Comment: You want to call a Function from `Debug.Print` command ?

Comment: The [Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/print-method) method does not have a "Object" parameter, it applies to an "Object" (which here is the Debug global object). It does not have named parameters either (only an outputlist)

Comment: I might be confusing methods and properties then.

Comment: @VincentG caveat: there is no global `Debug` object ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Debug` statements are indeed different from everything else. If you look for a `Debug` module in the *Object Browser*, you won't find it, even with hidden classes and members shown.

`Debug.Print` and `Debug.Assert` statements are literally baked into the language [parser] itself - the comma here doesn't mean "argument separator", instead it's a special-form syntax that is [apparently] reserved for `Print` methods (note: VBA user code cannot use `Print` for a method name, it's reserved).

So `Debug` statements are basically special kinds of *keywords*. IntelliSense / parameter quick-info is shown for *argument list* syntax elements, but syntactically, the "arguments" of a `Debug.Print` are an *output list*, exactly like the [Print statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/6f427c3d-2471-4cd8-8cae-2e2951918b51) does.

Note that the VBE automatically turns a `?` token into a `Print` statement:

```
Debug.? --> Debug.Print
```

There's quite a bit of historical baggage with `Print`: the keyword/command (and its `?` shorthand) was used in old BASIC dialects to output things to a screen... or an actual [dot matrix!] printer.

So the short answer is, `Debug` statements are made with keywords, not member calls - and that's why *IntelliSense* isn't of any use with them, since there aren't any arguments.

The [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) project has a fun story with these statements... because it isn't really possible to parse a typical `Debug.Print` statement any differently than any other implicit `callStmt` (i.e. it looks and parses like any other procedure call), we had to give the statement its own dedicated parser rule, and "declare" a fake `DebugClass` module and make `Print` a "method" of that "class" in order to be able to track uses like we do with other early-bound identifier references:

[image: VBE7.DLL;VBA.DebugClass.Print (procedure)]

But there really isn't such a thing: statements with an *output list* are baked into the language at the parser & compiler level, whereas literally every other member call you ever made in VBA was a *member* of some module - hit F2 and browse the members of the VBA standard library: you'll find `CLng` type conversion, `Now` and `DateAdd` date/time functions, `MsgBox`, `DoEvents`, and so many others - all belong to some module. But `Debug` statements are closer to a `Stop` or `Resume` keyword, handled at a lower level.

---

Further proof that there's more than meets the eyes - other than the simple fact that default syntax highlighting in the VBE will highlight both `Debug` and `Print` in bright keyword-blue, if you compile a COM-visible class written in C#:

```csharp
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("6F25002E-2C9F-4D77-8CCB-A9C0E4FB2EF1")]
public interface ITestClass
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void Print(string value);
    [DispId(2)]
    void DoSomething();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestClass))]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("6F25002E-2C9F-4D77-9624-6CA79D4F088A")]
[ProgId("PrintTest.Class1")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
public class Class1 : ITestClass
{
    public void Print(string value)
    {
        /* no-op */
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        /* no-op */
    }
}
```

..and then invoke it from VBA code...

[image: PrintMethodTest client code]

The `DoSomething` method can be invoked, but the `Print` method will throw error 438 - just like it would if you tried to qualify it with anything other than `Debug`. So how come `Print` works in an Access report's code-behind then?

The interface isn't documented so this is pure speculation, but there's an `IVBPrint` interface that looks very much like something VBA would be looking for:

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(000204F0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),
  nonextensible
]
interface IVBPrint : IUnknown {
    HRESULT _stdcall WriteText([in] BSTR strText);
    [propput]
    HRESULT _stdcall Column([in] long retVal);
    [propget]
    HRESULT _stdcall Column([out, retval] long* retVal);
};
```

If that's the case, then [error 438 is just VBA's way to say "IVBPrint implementation not found"](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/4888#issuecomment-479383218)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. This is definitely the type of information I can't find anywhere no matter how much I search and it's also more interesting than most things in the documentation.

Comment: @user7393973 I've edited this answer with more information. Let me know if you ever find any information on `IVBPrint` -- I'm very curous about the *actual* mechanics of it... but everything seems to point to `Debug.Print` being nothing more than VBA keywords that compile to member calls against a hidden COM object that isn't exposed anywhere in the standard library, that would be implementing this `IVBPrint` undocumented interface.

Comment: I would love to help with that but uhmm, that's a little bit over my knowledge... and by a little bit I actually mean a lot ^-^'

Comment: It seems that the [Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/input-function) function doesn't have named parameters either and can't be used with `VBA.` behind like this: `VBA.Input(VBA.FileLen(PathName:=file_path), #file_number)` even though most other functions can like `FileLen` in that example.